# How to make a selection in django-autocomplete-light using jquery?

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I want to make a selection of an option in django-autocomplete-light using Jquery. I tried $(selector).val(value).trigger('change'). But bot working. Any suggestions. I am using dev version dal 3.7.0.dev0